# byNames() and byName() in Azure DataFlow,How to use them in which scenarios?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to use byName() and byNames() in my flow.But I am not getting exact usage of it like am not finding any examples / scenarios . The Examples given by Azure are not clear. Please help .

Comment: Is there anything specific that you are trying to achieve using byName() or byNames()? If so, provide an example of the same.

Comment: Am not getting the usage of it. Can you provide very good examples to depict any scenario.

Comment: Am coming from Alteryx etl background, now am in ADF .Just consider as a Q/A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `byName()` searches for a column in a given stream name (stream name is optional). Look at the following example. Let's say you have source data as in the following image:

[image]

- I have added another column called team with value as `og` using derived column transformation.

[image]

- Now consider you want to populate a column based on whether it exists or not. If there is no column with given name, `null` values are returned. I used the following dynamic content in `derivedColumn1` transformation,

```
 toString(byName('team'))
```

[image]

- I get the following output:

[image]

- Since we have given `team` as a column, it populated each row of `new` column with corresponding `team` column value. Instead of giving `team`, if we give any other column name that does not exist, then the entire `new` column will be populated with NULL values.
- `byNames()` is similar to `byName()`. Instead of giving a single column, you give an array of column names. The following dynamic content is an example where I have given array of column names, along with stream (optional argument).

```
array(byNames(['gname','team'],'source1'))
```

[image]

- I got the following output:

[image]

- Here I am searching for columns `gname and team` in the stream `source1` (which has only id and gname columns). Since we are looking to get a column where it does not exist, it has populated the `new` column with `NULL`. If all the given column names exist, the values are populated accordingly.